# How to write an Identity-Visitor

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Let us assume I am using the Python3.g4 grammar:

How can I write a program that parses a python-script, walks the syntax tree and outputs the same old program?

Later I want to apply some changes to the program, but for now I would be happy if I could just reproduce the program.

By now I guess I lose some information when walking an *abstract* syntax tree and there is no easy way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are losing all the content of tokens on the a hidden channel. Therefore you have to check each token in your parse tree whether there is a hidden token in the `TokenStream` next to it that is not listed in the `ParseTree`.

For this the methods `getHiddenTokensToRight` and `getHiddenTokensToLeft` in the `BufferedTokenStream` should be the right tools for this work.

However if you just want a reproduction of the parsed input you should try to access the `TokenStream` directly and read out `Token` after `Token` from there without taking care of the channel the `Token` is on.
With that you should be able to reproduce the original input without many problems.